# Does Windows 8 RETAIL install extract OEM product key from BIOS?

Tags: windows, windows-8, bios, product-key

I am in a situation where I cannot use Magical Jelly Bean Product Key Finder since the hard drive has failed on a particular system from HP.  Sadly HP will only sell restore discs and I don't have the luxury of waiting a few days for these to arrive.  I do have a retail disc from another system and have read that a retail copy of Windows 8 (not 8.1) will extract the OEM key from the BIOS in such cases.  Is this indeed the truth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[When installing Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012, `setup.exe` uses the following priority logic for product keys:](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2796988/en-us)

- Answer file (Unattended file, `EI.cfg`, or `PID.txt`)
- OA 3.0 product key in the BIOS/Firmware
- Product key entry screen

So make sure there is no `unattended.xml`, `ei.cfg` or `PID.txt` on the DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are using same version of Windows 8 as factory installed Windows 8 will retrieve OEM key from BIOS. Otherwise try this link http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-retrieve-windows-8-oem-product-key-from-bios/

Comment: link-only answers are not helpful.  Websites like nextofwindows should burn in hell for requiring you to fill out a survey to see information that's in 10 different locations